# unicode can be used for emoji

Tags: javascript, css, unicode, fonts

I am using `opentype.js` to parse a series of font emoji, I tried to learn how [font awesome works](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css), then I realize that they use for example `{content: '\35'}`, `{content: '\f214'}`, these type of unicode for reference. I do need a large amount of unicode just like these to represent my characters. I wonder if there is a category of unicode that I better use to avoid conflicts. I will be so glad with any of the following,

- suggestions on writing such a unicode generator
- docs to look on

Comment: Are you looking for Unicode's private use area?

Comment: Are you trying to determine what Unicode code points are used for emoji?